# Is path.join(__dirname, 'views') no longer needed for rendering ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I was doing some testing while following a tutorial, and noticed they did not include:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Is this not needed to render ejs files, or maybe I was using it wrong on my previous project.

The

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

is there, and it renders  the ejs still. I don't quite understand how this is happening, and couldn't find anything online either.

Please note, I have a simple Hello World file named index.ejs file in a views folder.
Here is my simple code

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());

app.use(cookieParser('SecretStringForCookies'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'SecretStringForSession',
  cookie: {maxAge: 60000},
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(flash());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', (req,res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel
If you are using views directory as a root you don't need to mention in app.js but if you are using partials and other directories at that time you have to mention those directories in app.js with path.

Comment: Thanks for your help Smit.

Answer (score 0):

Ejs and Express will automatically look for a "views" folder by default.

If you want to change the default you can do so by using the views configuration

```
app.set('views', 'someotherfoldername')
```